# Is there a way to force delete a crd with failing webhooks?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubedb

The [kubedb](https://kubedb.com/) operator in this case has crashed and un-responsive - however I need to cleanup these resources.

```
 k delete redis r1 redis-queue --namespace cts --force --grace-period=0
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "redis.validators.kubedb.com": the server is currently unable to handle the request
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "redis.validators.kubedb.com": the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Comment: Have you used the helm chart to deploy KubeDB?

Answer (score 19):

There should be a resource of kind `MutatingWebhookConfiguration` or `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` which actually registers the `webhook` with Kubernetes API Server. You need to delete that resource first which deregisters the webhook from the Kubernetes API Server.

Temporary store kubedb-webhook configuration:

```
kubectl get ValidatingWebhookConfiguration redis.validators.kubedb.com \
  -o yaml > redis-validator.yaml
kubectl get MutatingWebhookConfiguration redis.validators.kubedb.com \
  -o yaml > redis-mutate-validator.yaml
```

Remove your resources:

```
kubectl delete redis r1 redis-queue --namespace cts
```

Bring back the webhook configuration:

```
kubectl apply -f redis-validator.yaml
kubectl apply -f redis-mutate-validator.yaml
```

Comment: unfortunately that  didn't work      ```k delete redis r1 redis-queue --namespace abc
redis.kubedb.com "r1" deleted
redis.kubedb.com "redis-queue" deleted`` I see this output but the terminal doesn't come back .

Comment: After deleting the webhook configuration, check that the custom resource does not have any finalizers set which will prevent deletion: 

`kubectl get redis -o custom-columns=name:.metadata.name,finalizers:.metadata.finalizers`

and if so then edit the object and remove the finalizers from .metadata.finalizers and try to delete it again.

Comment: The validation is still happening after having removed the configurations. Not sure what other component could be doing it